# Mobile App Analytics for iPhone and Android phonegap app: Google Analytics or Flurry?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, analytics, flurry

I want to add analytics statistics on my apps built with HTML5 & Javascript and wrapped in phonegap. 
Basicaly, it's just a web app, so I wonder if i can use the same Javascript code as a website to integrate Google Analytics. It would be great, because I will be able to use the same codebase for my android or iPhone apps. But I don't know how to integrate it (what domain name etc.)

But then I saw this blog post to integrate Flurry analytics in phonegap iPhone:
http://supersoju.com/blog/2011/03/29/using-flurry-tapjoy-apsalar-etc-with-phonegap-on-ios/

So now I wonder what's the easiest way to integrate analytics in a multiplatform phonegap App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Phonegap Google Analytics plugin -

http://phonegap.com/2011/05/04/phonegap-alytics/

and on GitHub here

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/GoogleAnalytics

Comment: Thanks a lot! And do you know if we need to warn the user (regarding Apple policy).

Comment: It may not be required to comply with Apple Policy, but it is the polite thing to do.